# Cannot rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, console

I'm having issues with the One Month Rails application.

I have run

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_pins user_id:integer:index
```

But when I try to run

```
rake db:migrate
```

directly after I generate the migration, I get this error:

```
    ==  AddUserIdToPins: migrating ================================================
-- add_column(:pins, :user_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "pins" ADD "user_id"     integer/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sqlite3-    1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in     `new'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `block in execute'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `block in log'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:430:in `log'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `execute'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:360:in `add_column'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:454:in `add_column'
/home/colin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `block in method_missing'
```

These are the contents of the file I generated with the migration:

```
    class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pins do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :pins, :user_id
  end
  def change
        Pins.reset_column_information    
    add_column :pins, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :pins, :user_id 
    end
end
```

I think this might be because I had multiple attempts at generating the migration, but I had deleted the previous migrations, so I'm not sure what caused this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add `user_id` column twice in the database.
`user_id` column is added to `pins` table while creating the pins table.
Notice that the migration failed on line(where you are trying to add user_id to pins table again)

`add_column(:pins, :user_id, :integer)
rake aborted!`

```
def change
    create_table :pins do |t|
      t.integer :user_id  ## Added first time
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :pins, :user_id
 end
def change
    Pins.reset_column_information    
    add_column :pins, :user_id, :integer ## Adding second time : Here you get the error 
    add_index :pins, :user_id 
end
```

Migration file should look like :

```
class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pins do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :pins, :user_id
    Pin.reset_column_information ## Model name should be singular
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you solved my problem, but it did unfortunately create another problem. Now I get the error:   "SQLite3::SQLException: table "pins" already exists: CREATE TABLE "pins" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime)"   When trying to db:migrate.

Comment: First you need to `rake db:rollback version=version_number` where replace version_number with `20140125191228`, if migration file is `20140125191228_create_pins.rb`

Comment: After this run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: You are a god. Thank you so much. Worked like a charm for me.